# Removing elements from list or not getting them in at all

Tags: c#, list, foreach

I have list of filenames.
I need to exclude files with keyword in their name.

I have tried:

```
List<string> fileList = Directory.GetFiles(path).ToList();    
foreach (string file in fileList)
    {
        if (file.Contains("KEYWORD"))
        {
             fileList.Remove(file);
        }
    }
```

Error I'm getting: The collection has been modified. The enumeration operation may not be started.
But it doesn't work. Do you know why or do you have any better solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Not clear from your question although this should work as it seems fine to me can you share the error you are getting

Comment: It should not work. He is changing the collection he is enumerating in foreach. You can use a traditional for loop, and examine elements in reverse order. That way you will safely go through all the positions in the list.
If you go start to finish, let's say you delete item at i = 1. Then you will have to recheck i = 1 and not go to i = 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
  List<string> fileList = new List<string>();
        fileList.Add("ioerhg");
        fileList.Add("ioerhg");
        fileList.Add("KEYWORD");

        List<string> fileListNew  = fileList.Where(x => !x.Contains("KEYWORD")).ToList();
```